# Install mod_jk with apt-get

Tags: apt, apache2, tomcat6

Is it possible to install **mod_jk** via **apt-get**? If yes, what is the name of the package?

Comment: Use apt-cache to search for packages e.g. in this case apt-cache search mod_jk gives you the details of the required package

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The package should be named *libapache2-mod-jk* .

You would therefore be able to use

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk
```